# How to get data from Microsoft Word Forms into Excel automatically using sharepoint site as the platform

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, ms-word

I was testing my vba code to transfer data from a word form over to an excel spreadsheet and both the excel and word form were saved on my C drive so the code for the path was written as
myfolder = "C:\Users\Suzanneg\OneDrive............. Running the macro was working fine and the data was transferring but i now have to move both my documents over to a sharepoint site.  I copied the path and replaced what i had against myfolder with the new path.  But it now is not taking over any data from the forms.  Is there an issue with using sharepoint as the holding place for the document and running macros?

I expected the data to move over as it was doing whilst the document were in my C drive

Comment: Welcome to the board.  Could you edit your question and include the VBA code please.  The edit button is at the bottom of your question.  Might also be worth having a read of [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Going off one of the comments in your original question does this open the file (assuming the file is _Toolkit Responses.xlsm_) - `Sub T(): Dim wrkBk As Workbook: Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open("https://highlandcouncil1.sharepoint.com/sites/WFWP/Shared Documents/Evaluation & Self Assessment/Highland Toolkit/Self assessment/E-FORM/Toolkit Responses.xlsm"): End Sub`